# Nested CSS counter does not show increment

Tags: css, counter

I am trying to use CSS counters to be applied to a series of elements and I miserably fail to get it right.

The HTML code is very simple:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: objgen;
}

span.general:before {
  content: counter(objgen);
  counter-increment: objgen;
}

span.general {
  counter-reset: objesp;
  font-weight: bold;
}

span.esp:before {
  content: counter(objgen) "." counter(objesp);
  counter-increment: objesp;
}

span.esp {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>inputs: </p>
<p><span class="general"></span> <input type="text" value="test1"></p>
<p><span class="esp"></span> <input type="text" value="test2"></p>
<p><span class="esp"></span> <input type="text" value="test3"></p>
<p><span class="general"></span> <input type="text" value="test4"></p>
<p><span class="esp"></span> <input type="text" value="test5"></p>
<p><span class="esp"></span> <input type="text" value="test6"></p>
```

The objgen counter runs OK but the objesp never increments its value: it is always equal to one. What am I doing wrong?

Is the problem coming from the fact that the span with class "esp" is not nested within the span with class "general"?

**COMMENT**

It seems that as pointed by Paulie_D the problem is with the structure, the following HTML works with no problem (it is not the only possibility):

```
<span class="general"></span><input type="text" value="test1">
<span class="esp"></span><input type="text" value="test2">
<span class="esp"></span><input type="text" value="test3">
<span class="general"></span><input type="text" value="test1">
<span class="esp"></span><input type="text" value="test2">
<span class="esp"></span><input type="text" value="test3">
```

Comment: I'm thinking this has something to do with the structure - https://jsfiddle.net/wvLmzurj/

Comment: Yep - https://jsfiddle.net/zsvwkwrk/1/

Comment: So it seems that the counters get out of scope with the <p> wrapper but that is bizarre....is the standard suppose to work like that?

Comment: I think so, the spec (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-lists-3/#creating-counters) is quite complex but I think this has to to with counter inheritance being in document order.

Comment: The "esp" elements have to be nested below the "gen" for this to work.

Comment: It does not need to be nested, it may also be a sibling as I tested with the comment in my post

Comment: As @Paulie_D has pointed out already, counters are extremely sensitive to HTML structure because that determines how the counters are inherited and how the incremented value is visible to another element. You'd find more information about that in the thread I've linked as duplicate target. In short, the `objesp` counter is created at `span` which is a child of `p`. Neither the `p` or its siblings have any idea about this counter existing or its value and so each such span creates its own version of `objesp` and sets it to 1.

Answer (score -1):

you are using class wrong. you don't need to assign the element **span** if you already assigned the element a class.

So instead of

```
    span.general -> .general
```

That might solve your problem.

```
            body {
            counter-reset: objgen; 
        }
        .general::before {
            content: counter(objgen) ;
            counter-increment: objgen;
        }
        .general {
            counter-reset: objesp;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .esp::before {
            content: counter(objgen) "." counter(objesp);
            counter-increment: objesp;
        }
        .esp {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

how about this?

Comment: Have you tested this to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: @Paulie_D  I am traveling while trying to solve the problem. Could not test it on mobile. Noticed some flaws that might solve the problem at hand.

Comment: The problem is not related to what you pointed out...it seems to be a problem with the structure as pointed out by Paulie_D

Comment: Unfortunately, this has nothing to do with classes.

Comment: @No-nonsense did you also change : to :: ?